# Displaying histogram plot openCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram

I have the histogram for an image which i have calculated. I want to display this as an image so that I can actually see the histogram. I think my problem is to do with scaling although i am slightly confused over the co ordinate system starting with 0,0 in the top left as well.

```c
int rows = channel.rows;
int cols = channel.cols;
int hist[256] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k<cols; k++ )
    {
        int value = channel.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,k)[0];
        hist[value] = hist[value] + 1;
    }
}

Mat histPlot = cvCreateMat(256, 500,CV_8UC1);
for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    int mag = hist[i];
    line(histPlot,Point(i,0),Point(i,mag),Scalar(255,0,0));
}

namedWindow("Hist",1);
imshow("Hist",histPlot);
```

This is my calculation for creating my histogram and displaying the result. If i do mag/100 in my second loop then i get some resemblance of a plot appearing (although upside down). I call this method whenever i adjust a value of my image, so the histogram should also change shape, which it doesn't appear to do. Any help in scaling the histogram and displaying it properly is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- please don't use cvCreateMat ( aka, the old c-api ), you also seem to have rows and cols wrong, additionally, if you want a *color* drawing, you need a color image as well, so make that:

  `Mat histPlot( 500, 256, CV_8UC3 );`
- image origin is top-left(0,0), so you've got to put y in reverse:

  `line(histPlot,Point(i,histPlot.rows-1),Point(i,histPlot.rows-1-mag/100),Scalar(255,0,0));`

Comment: Yes, that sorts my issue. It wasn't changing the plot because i was calling the above function before i was editing the image instead of after the image alterations. One final question though. Is it posibble to clear histPlot after it has been used? I display the plot in the window "Hist" and i want it to remain there and then update If i make changes to the image. Currently the function above is called but the new plot is overlay on the previous. I thought "Mat histPlot( 500, 256, CV_8UC3 );" would have cleared the content of histPlot each time the function was called.

Comment: I have a basic image editor, so i can change the contrast, sharpness, brightness etc of an image. Whenever I make a change i want to also display the current image histogram. The function above creates and then displays the histogram. Whenever i make an adjustment to the image the above function is called to update the histogram and display it in the same window. The issue is that although the new histogram is being created, the old histogram still appears in the histogram window "Hist". So instead of displaying the updated histogram, it overlays the updated histogram on the previous one.

Comment: sounds like you need to create a new histPlot Mat for every frame, and then draw the current hist into that